# Is it possible to format a specific piece of Apex code using Prettier in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, apex, prettier

In visual studio code, I can specify a specific range and press Ctrl + K & Ctrl + F to format the selected range, but it does not work well in Apex code.
We use Prettier as our formatting tool and it is compatible with APEX.

I strictly checked to see if the shortcut was registered in VS code and it was.

Comment: I think "format selection" uses the default vscode formatter and not prettier, maybe if you set up prettier as your default formatter and then press ctrl k ctrl f?

Comment: I set Prettier as the default formatter for VS code when I did my research. As a result, I found that in Java and other codes, Ctrl + F → Ctrl + K can be used for range formatting, but this is not feasible in Apex.